# How to 'onclick' close javascript after 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, onclick

I have two website's. 1 is my business site and other is my blog.

I receive a lot of traffic to my blog and I want to monetize that traffic for my other site.

I found out this javascript below :

```
(function(){

 var Xcord = 0,
 Ycord = 0,
 IE = document.all ? true : false;

 if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);

 var lbox = document.createElement('iframe');
 lbox.src = 'http://mybusinesssite.com/rssfeed';
 lbox.scrolling = 'no';
 lbox.frameBorder = 0;
 lbox.allowTransparency = 'true';
 lbox.style.border = 0;
 lbox.style.overflow = 'hidden';
 lbox.style.cursor = 'pointer';
 lbox.style.width = '120px';
 lbox.style.height = '10px';
 lbox.style.position = 'absolute';
 lbox.style.opacity = 100;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(lbox);

window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);

 setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(lbox);
window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
 }, 10000);

 function mouseMove(e) {
 if (IE) {
 Xcord = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
 Ycord = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
 } else {
 Xcord = e.pageX;
 Ycord = e.pageY;
 }

 if (Xcord < 0) Xcord = 0;
 if (Ycord < 0) Ycord = 0;

 lbox.style.top = (Ycord - 5) + 'px';
 lbox.style.left = (Xcord - 60) + 'px';

 return true
 }
})();
```

With this I can iframe my rss subscribe button from business site and display it by cursor on my blog.

The problem with script: It has timer, so when script is loaded it will close automatically after 10 seconds. I will mark that part in bold.

BUT

I need so when people only click the iframe it will close. Or even better, it will close in 5 seconds for example.

So when viewer on my blog click on RSS subscribe button they will be sent to my business site's rss feed and javascript/iframe on my blog will close.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how to set a function to execute after 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds):

```
setTimeout(function() {alert('Do something here!!!');},5000);
```

Comment: yes, but I need that when user click's on iframed part, iframe/javascript will close after 5 seconds...

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: `onclick="setTimeout(function() {window.close();},5000);"` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you want to do is you cannot detect a click within an iframe.  The only events you can listen for are if the cursor enters or leaves the iframe.  And since this code moves the iframe around with your cursor that adds a problem.

I'm not exactly sure why you would want to display an iframe that shows an rss feed and follows your cursor and close it on click.  I feel like this is a relatively bad user experience, but that being said here is some code that will do what you want.  It gets around the problem I mentioned above by creating another dom element that sits on top of the iframe and captures the click and removes itself and the iframe.  There are various other issues with this code that I wont get into, but hope this helps.

```
(function(){

    var Xcord = 0,
    Ycord = 0,
    IE = document.all ? true : false;

    if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);

    var lbox = document.createElement('iframe');
    lbox.id = 'mybusinesssite-rss-iframe';
    lbox.src = 'http://mybusinesssite.com/rssfeed';
    lbox.scrolling = 'no';
    lbox.frameBorder = 0;
    lbox.allowTransparency = 'true';
    lbox.style.border = 0;
    lbox.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    lbox.style.width = '120px';
    lbox.style.height = '10px';
    lbox.style.position = 'absolute';
    lbox.style.opacity = 100;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(lbox);

    var lboxdiv = document.createElement('div');
    lboxdiv.id = 'mybusinesssite-rss-overdiv';
    lboxdiv.style.width = '120px';
    lboxdiv.style.height = '10px';
    lboxdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    lboxdiv.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(lboxdiv);

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
    document.getElementById('mybusinesssite-rss-overdiv').addEventListener('click', removeMyBusinessSiteIframe);

    function mouseMove(e) {
        if (IE) {
            Xcord = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            Ycord = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        } else {
            Xcord = e.pageX;
            Ycord = e.pageY;
        }

        if (Xcord < 0) Xcord = 0;
        if (Ycord < 0) Ycord = 0;

        lbox.style.top = lboxdiv.style.top = (Ycord - 5) + 'px';
        lbox.style.left = lboxdiv.style.left = (Xcord - 60) + 'px';

        return true
    }
})();

function removeMyBusinessSiteIframe(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(document.getElementById('mybusinesssite-rss-overdiv'));
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(document.getElementById('mybusinesssite-rss-iframe'));
}
```

Comment: This closes the iframe as soon as you click, if you want it to close after 5 seconds let me know.

Comment: omg, it really works! Your the first one who really gave something that works... I even paid a freelancer, but he couldn't figure out this!

But yes, I need timer so after click, user would go to my feed and iframe will go away in 3 - 5 sec! Can you PM your email so can I hire you for my other projects? 

Thanks buddy and I am looking forward for timeout code! :) 

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, right now on click it's just closing iframe, and its not even clicking on my rss button... so I need that delay. :)
Thanks again bud!

Comment: Hi Squeee123, still waiting for your delay code... Please be so kind and write it asap. Thanks again.